# Umbraco 7 - Renaming Node name does not stop URL working

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco-blog

I had a node in my tree called Register, umbraco created this page with a URL of:

> Domain.com/register

Which is was I was expecting, then I decided to change the name of the node to "Register Step 1"

As I was expecting the URL changes and looking at it the umbraco back office the URL is now

> Domain.com/register-step-1

All good so far....right?

Ok but now if I navigate to Domain.com/register

Umbraco Automatically redirects me to Domain.com/register-step-1

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

In my scenario this behavior is actually good, means if someone has created link on an external site, they don't need to update it, the user will still see the page I want them to see, all with out me doing anything.

but in other scenarios this could be exactly what you don't want to happen, so how could I turn it off?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This url tracking is built into Umbraco as of Umbraco 7.5.x to avoid "dead" links. You can manage active redirects via the Redirect URL Management tab on the start page of the Content section.

The whole auto-redirect thing can be disabled if needed: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/URL-Tracking/ - go to umbracosettings.config and set

```
<web.routing disableRedirectUrlTracking="true" />
```